# Solving an equation using incremental nested for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to solve an equation using nested forloops.

I am trying to solve for (i,j,k) in the equation (-25)i + (14)j + (-8)k = -77. Norm is -77.

I have been trying to debug it but cant find the problem with my algorithm.

Here is my code:

```
int newx = -20; int newy = -20; int newz = -20;
test = true;
while(test){
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        if((f[0]*(newx+i) + f[1]*newy + f[2]*newz) == norm){
            System.out.println(f[0]*(newx+i) + f[1]*newy + f[2]*newz);
        } else {
            for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
                if((f[0]*(newx) + f[1]*(newy+j) + f[2]*newz) == norm){
                    System.out.println((f[0]*(newx) + f[1]*newy+j + f[2]*newz));
                } else {
                    for(int k = 0; k < 20; k++){
                        if((f[0]*(newx) + f[1]*(newy) + f[2]*(newz+k)) == norm){
                            System.out.println((f[0]*(newx) + f[1]*newy + f[2]*newz+k));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What output do you get? What do you expect? And what do you mean by "solving the equation"? Do you simply want to evaluate the equation on pre-set grid points? For me, it is not clear, what you are asking.

Comment: what is `norm`? Where is `test = false` or `break` or something that terminates the `while` loop?

Comment: @rakeb.void I tried that test = false but the loop was not terminating so I removed it.

Comment: @turning85 I updated it

Comment: If you're trying to solve `(-25)i + (14)j + (-8)k = -77`, you're going to need to have `(-25)*i + (14)*j + (-8)*k == -77` somewhere in your code. Assuming the code you posted is your actual code, you only ever use a single one of `i`, `j` or `k` in an equation (as opposed to all 3 in the same equation), so clearly that won't work. Also, your use of `-20 + ...` is weird and confusing. Is this your actual code?

Comment: Side note - you can obtain the value of `k` using the values of `i` and `j`, so you don't technically need to loop over that (I'll leave that for you to figure out if you wish to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach in general is convoluted. You're attempting to obtain the value of `i`, `j` and `k`. So keep it simple!

First, you're going to need to test every possible combination, so a triple nested for loop makes sense. Then, you're going to need to run the calculation and test the output. If the output is `-77`, you've found *one* solution for `i`, `j` and `k`. So breaking this down into stages we've got.

- Test every value for `i`, `j` and `k`.
- Plug `i`,`j` and `k` into the formula.
- If the `output` of the formula is `-77`, print the results.

So now we know the *stages*, let's turn that into some code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
     for(int k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
        // Go through each value.
        int output = (-25 * i) + (14 * j) + (-8 * k);
        // Plug the values into the formula.
        if(output == -77) {
            // Test and output.
            System.out.println("i = " + i + ", j = " + j + ", k = " + k);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Now, you do not know how many solutions you are going to get here, so I would create another class called `Solution`.

```
public class Solution {
    private int i;
    private int j;
    private int k;

    // Appropriate constuctor and getters.
}
```

That way, when you need to save it, you can say.

```
List<Solution> mySolutions = new ArrayList<Solution>();

// Nested for loops.

mySolutions.add(new Solution(i, j, k)); // Provided that you wrote the constructor
```

And you can override the `toString` method in the `Solution` object to print out a reasonable output..

```
public String toString() {
    return "i =" + i + ", j =" + j + ", k =" + k;
}
```

So when you output, it will look something like..

```
i = 1, j = 2, k = 10
i = 1, j = 6, k = 17
i = 3, j = 1, k = 2
```

**Check out..**

- I've made a simple version in [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/Og72We) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You are evaluating the inner `if` conditions incorrectly, e.g.:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
    if((f[0]*(newx) + f[1]*(newy+j) + f[2]*newz) == norm){
        System.out.println((f[0]*(newx) + f[1]*newy+j + f[2]*newz));
    }
    [...]
}
```

you forgot to add `i` to `newX`, it should be `f[0] * (newx + i)`. This applies to the `if` condition, as well as the `println(...)`. If you correct those bugs, you find a solution.

To get rid of the endless-loop:

- remove the `while` loop
- add `&& test` to each `for` loop condition
- add `test = false;` in each `if`-body

(This solution is quick and dirty, but I will let you figure out, how to solve it in a more appropiate fashion).

For a more elegant, overall solution please take a look at [christoper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31372155/4216641). There you find a (from a software engineer's point of view) cleaner solution, as well as some extensions you might want to have.